# Adding users through PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add users through my AC / DC with a powershell script then put those users in their assigned groups from a csv file. This is the code I have but when I put it into powershell and run it, it doesnt do anything. I waited about 30 min and nothing populated in for the users or groups. Does it usually take a while to add users and put them in groups or is there something I am missing?

```
$UserList = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop names.csv'

foreach ($User in $UserLis) {

    $Attributes = @{

        Enabled = $true
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
        Path = "OU=balrok Users, DC=balrok, DC=edu"

        Name = "$($User.First) $($User.Last)"
        UserPrincipleName = "$($User.First) $($User.Last)@balrok.edu"
        SamAccountName = "$($User.First) $($User.Last)"
        EmailAddress = "$($User,First)@balrok.edu"

        GivenName = $User.First
        Surname = $User.Last

        Description = $User.Age

        Group = $User.Group


        AccountPassword = "1234" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

        if (Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $SamAccountName){
            Write-Host "Added" $SamAccountName to $Group" -ForeGroundColor Green
        }
    }
    

    New-ADUser @Attributes
}
```

Comment: You have a variable `$UserList` for CSV data, but run foreach over `$UserLis`. Is that a typo in the question, or in production code too?

Comment: Along with the above typo, the `EmailAddress` has `$User,First` with a comma, also a space in the `UserPrincipleName` (userprincipalname?). Seems to be a few errors throughout that could be causing problems. `SamAccountName` can have a space but that is up to the Org.

Comment: You cannot have an if-clause inside a hash literal. The IF-clause should run after the user is created. I haven't tested, but I see problems with using add-groupmember inside the condition.

Comment: plus, you should create the new user first and then add this user to the group, not the other way around. Also, a SamAccountName must be 20 characters or less and depending on your users First and Last name you're likely to exceed that number

Comment: I fixed all those errors besides my add-adgroupmember. I went to run the code in powershell and it does not print anything just loads

Comment: Just tried running this without the if statement and I get an error with the UserPrincipleName and New-ADUser @Attributes